# How to add months and days for a simple interest-rate calculation (Java)

Tags: java, finance, calculation

I am working on a program for an assignment.
There I got stuck on how to add the **days and months** for my program.

I can already convert the *simple interest* into *years*, but not for months and days:

```java
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class SimpleInterest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double PAmount, ROI, TimePeriod, simpleInterset;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print(" Please Enter the Principal Amount : ");
        PAmount = scanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.print(" Please Enter the Rate Of Interest : ");
        ROI = scanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.print(" Please Enter the Time Period in Years : ");
        TimePeriod = scanner.nextDouble();

        simpleInterset = (PAmount * ROI * TimePeriod) / 100;

        System.out.println("\n The Simple Interest for Principal Amount " + PAmount + " is = " + 
        simpleInterset);   
    }    
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you thought of a general plan for this?

Comment: What is the purpose of _days_ and _months_? If they are subject to __daily- or monthly-compunding__ of the [nominal interest rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_interest_rate), do you need the math formula or is your issue bringing the formula into code?

Comment: i am supposed to code a simple interest program that shows years days and months for an assignment there was no mentioning of using the formula inside the code

Comment: Hey! Is this you or one of your fellows asking a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59079261/hello-i-got-a-question-the-teacher-asks-for-p-m-in-months-instead-of-p-a-it-als ?

Answer (score 1):

Just ask them separatly then compute the global time

```
System.out.print(" Please Enter the Principal Amount : ");
double pAmount = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());

System.out.print(" Please Enter the Rate Of Interest : ");
double rOI = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());

System.out.print(" Please Enter the Time Period in Years : ");
double years = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
System.out.print("And months : ");
double months = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
System.out.print("And days");
double days = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());

double timePeriod = years * months / 12 + days / 365;
double simpleInterset = (pAmount * rOI * timePeriod) / 100;

System.out.println("\n The Simple Interest for Principal Amount " + pAmount + " is = " + simpleInterset);
```

I'd suggest :

- don't define variable before using it if you don't need to do so
- use nextLine and parse what you need, you'll avoid suprise with return char
- as Java convention, use lowerCamelCase to name your variables

Comment: Seems the OP has __accepted your answer__ but needs more input: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59079261/hello-i-got-a-question-the-teacher-asks-for-p-m-in-months-instead-of-p-a-it-als